# Get and Set usando PROPERTY - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, conversão, getters-setters

A título de aprendizagem do **property**, criei um pequeno conversor de moedas. Veja:

```
class converteMoeda():


  def __init__(self, dollar=0, real=0):
    self.dollar = dollar
    self.real = real

  def toDollar(self):
    dollar = self.real/self.dollar
    print("Convertendo Reais para Dólar.")
    return(dollar)

  def toReais(self):
    reais = self.dollar/self.reais
    print("Convertendo de Dólar para Reais.")
    return(reais)

  def setDollar(self,dollar):
    print("Gravando valor do dólar.")
    self._dollar = dollar
  def setReais(self,real):
    print("Gravando valor do real.")
    self._real = real

  def getDollar(self):
    print("Recuperando valor do dólar.")
    return(_dollar)
  def getReais(self):
    print("Recuperando valor do Real.")
    reutrn(_real)

  real = property(getReais,toReais)
  dollar = property(getDollar,toDollar)

c = converteMoeda()
c.toReais(3.17)
```

No entanto, por um motivo que não consegui identificar, está me gerando um erro de número de parâmetros:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 35, in <module>
  File "python", line 5, in __init__
TypeError: toDollar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa aventura?

Comment: O método `toDollar` só recebe `self` como parâmetro. Se ele funcionar como um *setter* da propriedade, ele deve receber o novo valor da propriedade como parâmetro também.

Comment: Aliás, seu código possui vários erros de sintaxe.

Answer (score 2):

Criei um pequeno exemplo que tem como default o valor do dollar em 3.3, voce pode alterar e acessar esse valor em uma instancia da classe atraves da propriedade e do setter `us`.

### ([TL;DR](https://repl.it/JFrq))

```
class Convert:

    def __init__(self):
        self.us = 3.3

    def to_dollar(self, real=0):
        return real/self.__us

    @property
    def us(self):
        return self.__us

    @us.setter
    def us(self, us):
        self.__us = us

c = Convert()
reais = 16.67
```

**Utilizando a `@property` us:**

```
print ('valor atual do dollar: ', c.us)
valor atual do dollar:  3.3
```

**Utilizando o metodo to_dollar para conversão:**

```
print('Conversão de',reais,'reais em dollar: ',c.to_dollar(reais))
Conversão de 16.67 reais em dollar:  5.051515151515153
```

**Utilizando o `us.setter`:**

```
c.us = 3.10
print ('Valor Atualizado do dollar: ',c.us)
Valor Atualizado do dollar:  3.1
```

**Nova conversão após a a atualização com o setter:**

```
print('Conversão de',reais,'reais em dollar: ',c.to_dollar(reais))
Conversão de 16.67 reais em dollar:  5.37741935483871
```

[Veja o codigo rodando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JFrq)

Comment: Eu agradeço muito sua resposta! Funciona direitinho. Mas a minha dúvida maior é: é possível realizar duas operações usando o `property`? No meu exemplo, faço conversão Dollar->Real e Real->Dollar. Você saberia me dizer se é possível?

Comment: @SnowBG property não "realiza operações" apenas devolve o valor de uma "propriedade", vc pode realizar trocentas operações para devolver essa propriedade. bem simples.

Comment: @SnowBG p/ fazer o que vc deseja é só criar um novo metodo `to_real(self, us) return us*self.__us` e chama-lo assim `c.to_real(valor)`